# Returning a custom promise only when needed - what am I doing incorrectly?

Tags: angular

I am trying to write a function that returns a custom promise only when needed. The code looks like this:

```
login(sp: ServerProfile): Promise<any> {
    return this.logout(sp) // first logout
    .then(_ => {
        if (this.isAuthEnabled(sp)) {
          return this._login(sp) // if yes, re-login
          .then(succ => { this.utils.debug(`Logged in with: ${succ}`); this._isLoggedIn = true; })
        }
        else {
          this._isLoggedIn = true;
          return new Promise ( (resolve, reject ) => {resolve(true)}) //-> problem

        }

      })
  }
```

I know I can wrap the entire function in a `new Promise (resolve, reject)` but I don't want to unnecessarily wrap `this._login` as it returns a promise.

If I add the `new Promise` in the `else{}` part, I get this error:

> [ts] Argument of type '(_: any) => Promise | Promise<{}>' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type '(value: any) => void |
>   PromiseLike'.

Comment: Since you're using Angular you should be using **RxJS** instead of _Promises_. I think your login logic is strange, if the user is already logged in, why would you log him out and back in again instead of doing nothing (or redirecting him)?

Comment: because the "profile" (parameter) might be different - in which case he needs to log out of current session and log in with new credentials. I didn't explicitly put in that comparison to compare profiles because in my app, a login is only called if the profiles are different (if they are already logged in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the solution seems to be to specify `<any>` in the hand crafted promise

```
  return new Promise <any>( (resolve, reject ) => {resolve(true)}) //-> no problem
```